# Unable to install Midori browser on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Tags: apt, 18.04, midori

I am trying to install Midori to Ubuntu, starting with:

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:midori
```

The response is:

```
 Midori Browser
    http://twotoasts.de/index.php/midori/

This PPA is signed. To add the GPG key to your apt keyring:
   sudo apt-key adv --recv-keys --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com A69241F1
Starting with Karmic, adding the PPA and its key is as simple as:
   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:midori

You may also want to use the WebKit-team PPA:
     https://launchpad.net/~webkit-team/+archive/ppa
You can find unstable Midori versions at
    https://launchpad.net/~midori/+archive/midori-dev
 More info: https://launchpad.net/~midori/+archive/ubuntu/ppa
Press [ENTER] to continue or Ctrl-c to cancel adding it.

Hit:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease
Ign:2 http://ppa.launchpad.net/midori/ppa/ubuntu xenial InRelease                                                               
Hit:3 http://ch.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease                                                                      
Ign:4 http://ppa.launchpad.net/midori/ppa/ubuntu bionic InRelease                                                         
Hit:5 http://ch.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease                             
Hit:6 http://ch.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease                                                     
Err:7 http://ppa.launchpad.net/midori/ppa/ubuntu xenial Release                                                          
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.95.83 80]
Err:8 http://ppa.launchpad.net/midori/ppa/ubuntu bionic Release                                     
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.95.83 80]
Hit:9 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease               
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/midori/ppa/ubuntu xenial Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/midori/ppa/ubuntu bionic Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Is there an easy way how to deal with that?

Comment: @guiverc How do I check if it supports 18.04?

Comment: Did you look at the linked post?  As written in that post's answer; you can check the PPA main page, or go to the PPA download folder (which is what your machine will do).   It's the same steps as on that page; except the PPA in question is different.  In my first comment I already told you it was last active in 2015 (making it somewhat risky for 16.04, and a bad idea for 18.04...)

Comment: You seem not to have checked the ppa even for the correct version. Don't do this! PPAs are repositories from more or less untrusted users, which may install you a bitcoin miner or a crypto locker malware if you trust them without checking anything. See also https://askubuntu.com/questions/35629/are-ppas-safe-to-add-to-my-system-and-what-are-some-red-flags-to-watch-out-for for more details about trusting PPAs.

Comment: Oops the dupe has my answer....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like that PPA is a little stale but Midori can be installed on 64bit Bionic Beaver as follows:

```
sudo apt-get install libjavascriptcoregtk-1.0-0 libwebkitgtk-1.0-0
wget http://midori-browser.org/downloads/midori_0.5.11-0_amd64_.deb
sudo dpkg -i midori_0.5.11-0_amd64_.deb
```

This works well enough on my Bionic Beaver VM as the following screenshot demonstrates:

[image]

Mind you this is an older and perhaps not well maintained browser so just be a little careful...

Comment: @matousc Good news :)

Comment: @matousc, I agree with andrew.46 that Midori is not well maintained, and I would recommend that you try to find another one in order to be safer against attacks, that might use known security holes.

Comment: @sudodus Security holes are not an issues, because the browser will run in local network with trusted HW, SW and users.

Comment: @matousc, Will you or the trusted users browse the internet or browse only inside the local network? Is there a connection from the local network to the internet?

Comment: @sudodus No internet at all.

Comment: @matousc, Then it's OK :-)

Comment: also can be installed via snap, as they propose on their site https://www.midori-browser.org/downloads/. `snap install midori`

Comment: As of now, only `snap` is available - no **.deb** packages anymore! The correct way now would bne "sudo snap install midori" on Bionic Beaver! .... or building from source